Silicon Valley - season 3 episode 10 who is the cab driver who asks for Richard Hendricks
In the episode where Richard tells the truth about the Uptick to the investors, there is a Uber driver who asks for Richard and calls him a prick. Who is that guy? 


Do you mean who is the actor?

I meant that did he have any affiliation with the plot.

While he was in the meeting, Richard ordered a Uber to go home and get his laptop:

Neal and his blue Kia Sportage is around the corner.

Then when Richard and Erlich are arguing in the parking, the driver comes and says:

Are you Richard?

And Richard lies and sends him away.

No...

While the driver keeps on looking for the customer and turns his car, Richard and Erlich continue their argument which Erlich ends by:

Fuck *** Richard Hendricks, Fuck ***!

Revealing his name, and Neal hears it, and he is upset because he likely lost his time. That's why he insults him:

Richard Hendricks, hey! Prick.


Wow Silver, that was the exact answer I was looking for. Thanks
